# OpenCV Image Pyramids Display Issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use Image Pyramids with opencv for pose estimation. In particular I am using `pyrDown()` function. `ret_left_cv8UC` is the base image. I am storing the images as `std::vector<cv::Mat>`.

```
pyd_orgLeftIm.push_back(ret_left_cv8UC);
pyd_orgRightIm.push_back(ret_right_cv8UC);
for( int lvl=1 ; lvl<PYD_LEVEL ; lvl++ )
{
    cv::Mat __tmpL, __tmpR;
    cv::pyrDown( pyd_orgLeftIm[lvl-1],  __tmpL );
    cv::pyrDown( pyd_orgRightIm[lvl-1], __tmpR );

    pyd_orgLeftIm.push_back( __tmpL );
    pyd_orgRightIm.push_back( __tmpR );
}
```

It seem to work ok, I checked the image sizes and I get as expected. However, with the display it shows up strangely (issue with aspect ratio, I think).

The base image looks correct. How do I enforce the others to show up correctly.

My display code --

```
for( int lvl=0 ; lvl<PYD_LEVEL ; lvl++ )
{
    char strL[100], strR[100];
    sprintf( strL, "org_imgLeft_%d", lvl );
    sprintf( strR, "org_imgRight_%d", lvl );
    cv::imshow( strL, pyd_orgLeftIm[lvl] );
    cv::imshow( strR, pyd_orgRightIm[lvl] );
    cout << pyd_orgLeftIm[lvl].rows << ", "<< pyd_orgRightIm[lvl].cols << endl;
}
```

I would also like to add that, initially the display is correct (correct aspect ratio for smaller images), but as soon as I put my mouse over images they scale to fit the window as shown in the screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that the images are stretched because the toolbar is wider than the images. You can specify that you want the images to keep the correct aspect ratio at all times with the `cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` constant added to the window flags using `cv::namedWindow`. This would cause the image to be stretched both vertically and horizontally. You can also remove the toolbar alltogether with `cv::CV_GUI_NORMAL`.

```
int flags = cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | cv::CV_GUI_NORMAL;
cv::namedWindow( strL, flags );
cv::imshow( strL, pyd_orgLeftIm[lvl] );
```

There is a nice introduction to loading and displaying images in [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html).

Comment: sort of works but the images are blown up in size rather than stay small. Any idea on how to keep the aspect ratio while not blowing the image sizes.?

Comment: @mkuse If you're using the Qt backend to the highgui module, you can have the toolbar removed with the cv::CV_GUI_NORMAL flag. Edited the answer to include this.